# Migrate OpenERP 7.0 (with PostgreSQL 9.2) from one server to another?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am very new to OpenERP and PostgreSQL. For some reasons our company wants to move our existing OpenERP 7.0 to new machine. We are using OpenERP 7.0 with PostgresSQL 9.2 on Microsoft Server 2012, and our new server will be the same.

I will highly appreciate if someone may kind enough to answer my following questions:

1. What steps I may need to follow in order to migrate OpenERP 7.0 from one server to another with same version (7.0)?
2. OpenERP 7.0 has been changed in Odoo now, to migrate OpenERP 7.0 from one server to another, where could I able to download OpenERP 7.0 to fresh install into new machine ?
3. How could I backup and restore database in use by OpenERP 7.0 from PostgreSQL 9.2 (in Windows). Can I use PG_Admin to backup the database after Right Click on Database to take the backup?
4. any other information that could help me to do the migration.

Thanks & regards

Comment: Having just now done a quick check, these are all things that google with give you the answers to.  I suggest you try to do the migration, and if you run into a problem, ask a more specific question then.  As it stands, this question is not a very good fit for this site as it is not a single question, but multiple.

Comment: miR is right on this. Too many questions and nothing about programming. But i won't leave you alone on this: You can backup your database on the gui (database manager) and you should install the same postgreSQL and the same OpenERP/Odoo ([Nightly](http://nightly.odoo.com/7.0/nightly/)). Then just use the gui database manager again, to import your database.

Comment: Thank you very much for you folks (Appreciated), But I do not agree with miR. In my opinion: these types of open forums are for sharing knowledge, experience, and to help each other. Asking three questions with three different questions titles serve the same purpose if they are co-related. What my expectations were to get a hint before taking any step forward. But I really demotivated after reading such comments. Please accept my apologies for any inconvenience. Thanks!